# Why end point returning below error while processing request?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

Details:- Have added Datamapper in-process module of my wso2 project. But when I send request JSON using command prompt to my back-end service I get below error from the endpoint.

--In console window of Integration studio.

Details:- From below logs, I can say it pass through a log module just before endpoint.

```
[2020-02-18 15:25:14,521]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - message = Routing to clemency medical center

[2020-02-18 15:46:22,301]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - message = Routing to clemency medical center
```

---In Command Prompt getting error:-

```
F:\WS02\WSO2 Integration Studio\Request_JSON\HelathCare\Transforming Message Content>curl -v -X POST --data @request.json http://localhost:8280/healthcare/categories/surgery/reserve --header "Content-Type:application/json"
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8280 (#0)
> POST /healthcare/categories/surgery/reserve HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8280
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type:application/json
> Content-Length: 200
>
* upload completely sent off: 200 out of 200 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Accept-Ranges: none
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
< Set-Cookie: SERVERID=s0; path=/
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Via: HTTP/1.1 forward.http.proxy:8080
< Date: Tue, 18 Feb 2020 10:16:27 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
Error in executing request: POST /clemency/categories/surgery/reserve* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Below are request and response JSON content have used.

1. Request content (client requested content in below format)

   ```
   {
     "name": "John Doe",
     "dob": "1940-03-19",
     "ssn": "234-23-525",
     "address": "California",
     "phone": "8770586755",
     "email": "johndoe@gmail.com",
     "doctor": "thomas collins",
     "hospital": "grand oak community hospital"
   }
   ```
2. The response we expect using data mapper from back end service.

   ```
   {
     "patient": {
       "name": "John Doe",
       "dob": "1990-03-19",
       "ssn": "234-23-525",
       "address": "California",
       "phone": "8770586755",
       "email": "johndoe@gmail.com"
     },
     "doctor": "thomas collins",
     "hospital": "grand oak community hospital"
   }
   ```

Comment: Can you share the synapse artifacts that you have used?

Comment: Hi Arunan .. Data mapper have used after propery mediatior in work flow and then after there is switch case to route request to requested hospital. Please find below link which give you idea what have done  ..https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI600/Transforming+Message+Content

Comment: Are you receiving any other errors in the console of Integration Studio other than `INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - message = Routing to clemency medical center
`?

Comment: No ..I did not receive any other error except this [2020-02-19 16:43:18,370]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - message = Routing to clemency medical center.  It is coming from Log just before end point.  Have used  get property to do so (fn:concat('Routing to ', get-property('Hospital')))

Comment: Hi @ArunanSugunakumar ..any luck with error..Have tried many times but did not understand. I also have made another sample API and create the workflow for it .. I have made the change  in request JSON file ..which posts my data and mapped that request with the response that JSON using Datamapper mediator in workflow ..still I am not able to do so ..It failed ..Below error have received in the console of an integrator.

Comment: @ArunanSugunakumar  Please find below error received ..[2020-02-20 17:13:48,052] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils} - The system cannot infer the transport information from the /TodolistAPI/api/TodoItems URL.
[2020-02-20 17:13:48,053] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender} - Unexpected error during sending message out org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system cannot infer the transport information from the /TodolistAPI/api/TodoItems URL.

Comment: Request format Json      {
    "User":{
    "id":1,
    "isComplete":true
 },
 "name":"One plus 3T"
  }   Response required  in format  {
    "id":2,
    "name":"Nokia 360",
 "isComplete":false
  }

Comment: Can you mention the Integration Studio version? Also please mention whether you are using the Micro Integrator embedded in the Studio, or pointed to a seperate EI server?

Comment: Hi Arunan.I am using an integration studio v6.6. I am able to get a response now .just a small mistake I am not providing workflow input and output type. Have provided proper Input and output type to data mapper mediator and it works.  Thankyou so much for your assistance Arunan

Comment: Glad to hear :-)

Answer (score 0):

In case of Using the data mapper approach just be sure on input and output schema you are providing and after successfully mapping input and output for conversion from XML to JSON vice versa. Please ensure the properties of Data-Mapper make input and output as per your requirements.

By default it set to XML to  XML.
[image]